# Valueallowunset not functioning as expected

Tags: knockout.js

Using knockout here.  I have a html like this:

```
 <p>
Choose:
<select data-bind="options: countries
                   value: selectedCountry,
                   valueAllowUnset: false
                   "></select>
</p>

<p>Choice: <span data-bind="text: selectedCountry"></span> </p>

<button data-bind="click: changeCountry">Change Value</button>
```

And script like this:

```
function ViewModel() {
    var self = this;
    self.countries = ['list1','lsit2','list3'];
    self.selectedCountry = ko.observable('list4');
    self.changeCountry = function()     {
        self.selectedCountry('NEGA booom');
    };


ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel());
```

The displayed text in the span is correct on load and on click of the button.  It does not update when I change the drop down though.

I read a bunch of documentation on knockout and do not understand how 'valueAllowUnset' works

EDIT: A little bit  more about this problem:  I have a list the renders dynamically based on a few other selections chosen.  Because the `selectedCountry` is a `ko.observable`, when that list clears to be updated all the `<options>` disappear, and the value of `selectedCountry` is set to `undefined`.

[removed fiddle]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to use `valueAllowUnset` with ko 3.0 version but it was introduced later from ko 3.1 check **[here](http://www.knockmeout.net/2014/03/knockout-3-1-released.html)**

> **valueAllowUnset option :** There is now a valueAllowUnset option for scenarios where the value does not match what is contained in the
>   options:
>
> - With this option set to true, Knockout does not force the value to    match an existing option.
> - The selection will be set to an empty option in the case of a    mismatch, but the value is not overwritten.

coming to your issue as you are updating with some value which doesn't exist in options making things go haywire in such cases `valueAllowUnset` is a savior which sets dropdown selection to empty making things not to go out of sync .

**view :**

```
<p>Choose: <select data-bind="options: countries,,optionsCaption:'-select-',value: selectedCountry,valueAllowUnset: true"></select></p>
<p>Choice: <span data-bind="text: selectedCountry"></span> </p>
<button data-bind="click: changeCountry">Change Value</button>
```

check **[here](http://jsfiddle.net/9300ngdw/5/)** for working sample

Comment: Found a work around -- before my list renders and there are no options (which is what sets the value of `selectedCountry` to `undefined` and what `valueAllowUnset` is intended to handle, I set the options of the `<select>` to `selectedCountry`.  This has solved my problem and doesn't rely on using `valueAllowUnset`.  However, my problem was not the same as my question, so I will accept this answer as well as leaving this explanation here in hopes that it will someday help someone.

Answer (score 0):

Its kinda late answer I suppose, but since I'm already here...
The problem is in coma missing after "options" binding.
Knockoup just applies options binding and ignores the rest since it is failing to parse it.